# Maven Subversion scm configuration for release plugin

Tags: svn, maven

I am attempting to use `$HOME/.scm/svn-settings.xml` to coax Maven into invoking svn with the `--trust-server-cert` option to bypass some self-signed server certs.  Maven appears to pass along the correct option when invoking `mvn scm:update` per http://maven.apache.org/scm/subversion.html, but not when invoking `mvn release:prepare`.  Presumably the config file only configures the scm plugin - so how do I get the release plugin to pass the trust server cert option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the release plugin doesn't support the scm config until version 2.2 - specifying the release plugin version explicitly fixed the problem.

Comment: Which version doesn't work, and more importantly, which version of the release plugin does work? Just add it to your answer for future reference.

Comment: 2.1 didn't work and 2.2.1 did (but I already noted that second part).